# Production React app functioning except Spotify log-in redirect path "not found on server"

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, app.yaml, spotify-app

Production ReactJS app, integrates Spotify Web Api (https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference-beta/) using Google App Engine: https://widget-dashboard-app.appspot.com/

All of the routes (`/settings`, `/about`, `/contact`) work as expected BUT when a user tries to log in to Spotify, the redirect path `/settings/#access_token=[BIG-LONG-TOKEN]&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600` results in this error via GAE:

```
Error: Not Found
The requested URL /settings/ was not found on this server.
```

My first thought is that I have an issue in my `app.yaml` file:

```
# [START runtime]
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
# [END runtime]

# [START handlers]
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: build/index.html
  upload: build/index.html
- url: /
  static_dir: build
- url: /.*
  static_files: build/static/\1
  upload: build/static/.*
- url: /settings/.*
  static_files: build/static/\1
  upload: build/static/.*
# [END handlers]
```

I've scoured the Interwebs in search of what might be the issue for two weeks. I've read all. the. docs.

Actual result should be: User logs in via Spotify's Web API, and is redirected back to `https://widget-dashboard-app.appspot.com/settings/#access_token=[BIG-LONG-TOKEN]&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600` and their browser will begin playing music within a few seconds. This works in development.

Answer (score 0):

As it's an SPA with your routing handled by the app, you need a catch-all route that lands on your main `index.html`. So it looks like your wildcard rule should be this:

```
url: /.*
  static_files: build/index.html
  upload: build/index.html
```

I don't think you'll need the `/settings/` one